# Difference between C5.0 and a 'regular' decision tree

Tags: cart

After reading some descriptions of C5.0 trees, it appears to me that it is the same as using e.g. sklearn `DecisionTreeClassifier` with `criterion='entropy'`.

Is there a principle difference between those, or is C5.0 essentially a decision tree that uses information gain?

Thank you